# select a string from file csh

Tags: string, csh

I have a file `file.dat` as follow:

```
1.1,2.1 1.4
3.1,2.1 2.4
2.4,4.5 11.5
..
```

And I want to select each time the whole line (string) and replace it in another file. So far I tried the following

```
#!/bin/csh

set FILENAME = 'file.dat' # file in which the strings are
set str = "229.8,230.9 230.36" # initialize the first string
set n = 1
while ( $n <= 3 ) # number of lines in the FILENAME
   echo Testing the first string $str
   set rep = $(head -n $n "$FILENAME")
   @ n++ # increment the index
end
```

When I tried to launch the script `csh launch.sh` I obtained the follow error message

```
Testing the first string 229.8,230.9 230.36
Illegal variable name. # connect with the rep definition(?)
```

The file in which I want to change the string `str` is as follow (this is btw a secondary problem which I could figure out by myself once I understand what's wrong in the first lines):

```
# Name    Type Par    
Mi        FI   154.2355189465 
So        UN   229.8,230.9 230.36 # line to be changed
Za        FI   0.8000020209
```

May somebody help me, please?

Comment: Why do your title and tags say `bash` when your code actually uses `csh`?

Comment: @melpomene because if a solution using `csh` is not found I will be anyhow happy with a solution involving `bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(...)` is Bash syntax for *command substitution* in Bash.

[In C-shell you have to use backticks instead (yuck).](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.osdevice/c_cmd_subs.htm)